# how to Fix Chrome Tag my site as Dangerous

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome

[image: My site show in the certification that is dangerous]

I'm new with this kind of issues, and i'm pretty sure that maybe it's small issue , please any help

Comment: Not just chrom, most moder browser will show that. You need to setup SSL for yourself. If you are using managed hosting most probably it gives you free Let's Encrypt SSL that you can install on your website, if not a google with your host name and `Install SSL WordPress on hostinger` will fetch you the step.

Answer (score 0):

is your website available via http or https? Chrome does mark every http-website as dangerous automatically. You need https.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your site to use SSL. For that you need to setup the server properly and get a SSL certificate. There are some services that allows you to create your own certificate for free, but not every hosting provider accepts them. In some cases you need to buy the certificate from your provider.

The most popular free certificate site is Let's Encrypt. You can read more on how to configure it on their site: https://letsencrypt.org.

Start with reading this: https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

You can read why google marked this site as **Dangerous** in this article [click here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95617?hl=en#zippy=%2Cnot-secure-or-dangerous). 
 If you are using WordPress in your registered domain then contact your hoisting provider about this issue. But if you are using free sites then I would recommend using XAMPP (Localhost) or you can use website like [Pantheon](https://pantheon.io/) to install and use WordPress. 
If you face problem on how to use this site then follow [this](https://youtu.be/-G_p-apW6rI?t=331) YouTube link to learn how this site works. It will start at 5:31.